# Applying a map function on Dataframe will convert into an RDD everytime?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Is applying a MAP() on Dataframe, always converts DF into RDD.

```
scala> val custDF = sqlContext.read.format("com.databricks.spark.avro").load("/user/cloudera/practice1/problem7/customer/avro")
**custDF: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame** = [customer_id: int, customer_fname: string, customer_lname: string]
```

```
scala> val a = custDF.map(x=>x(0)+"\t"+x(1)+"\t"+x(2))
**a: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[String]** = MapPartitionsRDD[106] at map at <console>:36
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Ethan, I just want to know that everytime applying a map() on DF will give result as RDD? is this correct?

Comment: But Why after applying a MAP() on DF converts it to RDD, that I don't know. Anyone have answer then please let me know.

Comment: What spark version are you using?  And I'm still not sure what the question is, this seems to be an observation.

Comment: @Ethan: My question is - Why DF converts to RDD after applying Map function? I am using spark1.6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Spark 1.6, DataFrames don't keep track of the type of the underlying data. This means that `map` has no meaning over a `DataFrame`. However, when you call `map` on it it runs over the underlying `RDD`. This is just a design limitation of Spark 1.6. You can convert it back to a DataFrame if you need those operations. If you update to Spark 2.2 or higher, you can use a `DataSet`, which is a `DataFrame` with a type parameter. You can run a `map` over that and get a `DataSet` back.